# how to solve the mapping value error in pubspec.yaml?

Tags: flutter

**pubspec.yaml**

getting this error Error... on line 39, column 10: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?

```
name: myvoapp
description: A new Flutter application.


publish_to:
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  flutter_login: ^1.0.14
  record_mp3: ^2.0.0
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  path_provider: ^1.6.11
  audioplayer: ^0.8.1
  stop_watch_timer: ^0.5.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.5
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
  animated_text_kit: ^2.2.0




dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

   assets:
    - images/icon1.png
```

I checked with spaces but could no solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, your `assets` indentation was wrong:

Use the content below:

```
name: myvoapp
description: A new Flutter application.


publish_to:
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  flutter_login: ^1.0.14
  record_mp3: ^2.0.0
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  path_provider: ^1.6.11
  audioplayer: ^0.8.1
  stop_watch_timer: ^0.5.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.5
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
  animated_text_kit: ^2.2.0




dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  # assets indentation was wrong
  assets:
    - images/icon1.png
```

Answer (score 0):

After try different things the solution for mi was the indentantion, spaces

uses-material-design: true
assets:
- images/

Make sure is align